# Save data associated with module for IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin for IntelliJ-IDEA. My plugin is a synchronization plugin which requires an ID for the data that it's synchronizing. Right now, whenever a user either pushes or pulls data from the cloud, they need to enter that ID. I want the user to be able to specify the ID at the time they create the module for their project. I want to save data associated with a module.

This is what I have so far.

```
package com.michaelsnowden.gas.module;

import com.intellij.ide.util.projectWizard.ModuleWizardStep;

import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * @author michael.snowden
 */
public class GASModuleWizardStep extends ModuleWizardStep {
    @Override
    public JComponent getComponent() {
        final JPanel jPanel = new JPanel();
        JTextField textField = new JTextField("My GAS project id");
        jPanel.add(textField);
        return jPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateDataModel() {
        JTextField textField = (JTextField) getComponent().getComponent(0);
        String projectId = textField.getText();
        System.out.println(projectId);
        // Now how do I save this projectId and associate it with the module?
    }
}
```

How do I save the `projectId` with the module I'm creating so that I can access it later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.intellij.openapi.module.Module` provides some methods to store simple arbitrary string values with user specifiable string keys. These methods are `setOption`, `getOption` and `clearOption`. The keys and values will be stored in the module's .iml file as attibutes to the `<module>` tag.

For more elaborate configuration storage you can implement a [PersistentStorageComponent](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/persisting_state_of_components.html). Use this if you want to store more than one value or more complex data structures than a simple string. See [org.jetbrains.idea.devkit.build.PluginBuildConfiguration](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/master/plugins/devkit/src/build/PluginBuildConfiguration.java) for an example of storing state to the module file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10639349)

Comment: I have improved my answer. Is this better?

Comment: Yes. Very much so. Perhaps you could provide an example to help the OP?